# If Data validation = Yes, then run formula

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a data validation cell that says either Yes or No.

I want my formula:

```
=IF(B7<=F7,G7,IF(B7<=F8,G8,IF(B7<=F9,G9,IF(B7>F10,G10))))
```

to run only if I set the first data validation cell to "Yes".

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap it in another IF:

```
=IF(A7="Yes",IF(B7<=F7,G7,IF(B7<=F8,G8,IF(B7<=F9,G9,IF(B7>F10,G10)))),"")
```

Where `A7` is the cell that is either `Yes` or `No`